# limpar campo se só existir tags html em campo texto

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um campo texto que permite códigos html. Quando o campo está vazio é passado as tags `<p><br></p>` por baixo dos panos, se eu dou vários enter no campo por baixo dos panos é inserido varias tags `<p>`. Como posso fazer uma validação para verificar se o campo está vazio desta forma?

Exemplo: digitei vários enter e salvei o texto, no backend é mostrado o valor de `"<p><br></p><p><br></p><p><br></p>` para o campo, porem ele se encontra vazio, queria  fazer uma validação para que se houver SOMENTE tags HTML quer dizer que o campo está vazio e não posso permitir que salve.

Fiz a validação:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.InformacaoObjetivo))
                    {
                        ErrorMessage = "Por favor, preencha o campo Texto.";
                    }
```

porém não está entrando no if pois apesar do campo estar vazio existem tags que estão passando para o campo.

Comment: Não é uma boa prática o que vou dizer, mas, tente: `model.InformacaoObjetivo.Substring(model.InformacaoObjetivo.IndexOf('<'), model.InformacaoObjetivo.LastIndexOf('>') + 1).Trim()`. Isso irá cortar todas as tags presentes na string

Comment: mas eu nao posso cortar as tags pq é permitido usar, exemplo se eu colocar la <p> e digitar um texto, tem que permitir, porem quando tiver somente <p> sem texto algum nao posso permitir entendeu ?

Comment: Altere como as coisas funcionam  "debaixo dos panos", ou seja, trate antes de inserir as tags html. Se a pessoa só deu enter ou espaços, ao invés de inserir <p>... não insira nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque os seus < p>, < br>, e < /p> por vazio e verifique o conteúdo.

```
string temp = model.InformacaoObjetivo;
temp = temp.replace("", "<p>");
temp = temp.replace("", "</p>");
temp = temp.replace("", "<br>");
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(temp))
{
    ErrorMessage = "Por favor, preencha o campo Texto.";
}
```

Se passou do if, é por que model.InformacaoObjetivo não esta vazio.

Comment: mas e quando eu utilizar a tag <p> ? vai ser removida e nao pode, tenho que remover só se nao houver conteudo no campo

Comment: O seu código não irá produzir o que você quer fazer. `temp` não terá seu valor alterado pois `Replace` (e não `replace`) retorna uma nova *String* com o texto alterado, e não altera seu invocador.

Comment: você vai remover as tags <p> apenas para testar se a string esta vazia. A variável temp é apenas para o teste, você continua trabalhando com o model.InformacaoObjetivo.

Comment: Nao posso fazer assim pois sempre vc ta mandando substituir <br> por vazio, se eu tiver um texto com novo paragrafo por exemplo em HTML não vai pegar pois vc ta pedindo pra sempre remover

Comment: se você tiver um texto: "texto qualquer<br>" e substituir o br por nada, e checar se o restante da string está vazio, já vai saber que não está. Remover as tag's é somente para checar se existe texto...

Comment: entendi, vou deixar assim mesmo, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro você usar Regex para verificar se existe caracteres dentro das tags.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("[a-z]");
var html = "<p></p>";



Match match = regex.Match(html);
if (regex.IsMatch(html))
{
  Console.WriteLine("Por favor, preencha o campo Texto.");
}
```

Comment: Assim nao vai funcionar, dei varios enter no campo e depois passei dfg, nesse caso ele tem que permitir pois ha "textos" no campo, porem nessa condição o sistema barra pois existem tags <p>

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião seria mais fácil(não só fácil, mas inteligente) tratar esse html inconsistente ao invés de ficar tratando quando existi-lo.
Mas..que tal usar uma biblioteca? Experimente `HtmlAgilityPack`

```
public void Main()
{
    var caso1 =  @"<p><br></p>";
    var caso2 =  @"
        <p><br></p>
        <p><br></p>
        <p><br></p>";
    var caso3 =  @"<p><br><p>hola</p></p>";

    Console.WriteLine(checaHtml(caso1)); //1 -> ok
    Console.WriteLine(checaHtml(caso2)); //3 -> tratar, seilá reescrever o valor do caso 1
    Console.WriteLine(checaHtml(caso3)); //1 -> ok
}

public int checaHtml(string html) {
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);     
    var elem = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("p/br");
    if (elem != null){
        return elem.Count;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yWzWWK